# How would you read '71 and how did the title suit with the film's story?

Tags: title, 71

Recently I saw the movie *'71* and loved it. However what confused me was what did the title mean, as in how would you read it *'dash' seventy one*? Does it mean *year 71* as the story is set during early 70s or something else?

Comment: It's just short for 1971 which was the height of the Irish "Troubles".

Comment: It is common to use an apostrophe as a mark for an abbreviation. It is read/spoken as simply "71." Do a google image search for "57 chevy model kit" and you will see this on the box art.

Comment: @Yorik put it in the answer, i shall tick it

Answer (score 2):

You watched the movie but didn't understand the title?  Seems like you need to rewatch it, as

> Hook's platoon is sent to Belfast in 1971 in the early years of the Troubles.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%2771_(film)

Comment: Well i had checked wiki and hence i could point out the year 1971 point. Moreover i didnt understand the title had nothing to do with my understanding of the film.